# Python Selenium Focusing a Certain Browser Window

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Currently, I'm having a script that opens multiple windows and only one is in focus/front.
Sometimes a different one needs to be in focus/front, I tried it  `with driver.switch_to.window`, but the window is still in the background.

I'm looking for a solution to get a certain window in focus/front, so I can perform a keyboard enter with `pyautogui.press('enter')`.

Thanks!

Code im currently having for testing, as the website i want to perform it on only throws the error i want to bypass after a certain amount of time.

```py
def testing:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get('https://www.alternate.de/login.xhtml')
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login:form-login:email"]').send_keys('email')
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login:form-login:pwd"]').send_keys('password')
    driver2 = webdriver.Chrome()
    #solution for focussing on first window
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    time.sleep(4)

testing()
```

Comment: Please share your relevant code, if possible including the link to web page you are running on. Otherwise this question will be closed in the same way as the previous.

Comment: Done! Hope this explains, im far from being an expert here.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are creating a new driver with `driver2 = webdriver.Chrome()`? Usually you can use only one driver and switch between windows with something like `driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])`, which will switch focus to the last opened window.

Comment: Not specific, this was only for testing in the real process one script will be ran multiple times which equals to multiple browsers.